calculating length of equiangular spiral in JavaScript
Is it possible to calculate the length of the spiral generated by this code?
And, if it requires heavy computational power, can the length be approximated more easily?
I'm applying this to thousands of elements in a PixiJS application, and I'd like to make the duration of the animation a function of the length, at least approximately.
I converted the Julia code from this post to JavaScript to generate a spiral between two points.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73043258/drawing-an-equiangular-spiral-between-two-known-points-in-julia
let p1 = [1000,1000]
, p2 = [0,0]
, r = Math.hypot(p2[0]-p1[0],p2[1]-p1[1])
, theta_offset = Math.atan((p1[1]-p2[1])/(p1[0]-p2[0]))

//# Number of points
, rez = 1500
//# Number of revolutions
, rev = 5
//# Radius as spiral decreases
, t = 0
, tRange = r
//# Angle as spiral decreases
, theta = 0 + theta_offset
, thetaRange = 2*(Math.PI)*rev
, x , y
;

spiral()
function spiral(){
 
  for (let i=1; i<rez + 1; i++) {  
      t = tRange  * (i/rez)
      , theta = thetaRange  * (i/rez)
      , x = Math.cos(theta) * r * Math.exp(-t) + p2[0] 
      , y = Math.sin(theta) * r * Math.exp(-t) + p2[1] 
      console.log(x,y)  
    }
  
}

Thanks!
